# Как выводить определённые элементы через migx

Tags: modx

У меня имеется 3 колонки(`<div class="we-produce__col">`) и в каждую колонку нужно вывести определённое количество карточек и определённые карточки(в 1-ую колонку 2 первых карточки, во 2-ую колонку 3-юю карточку и в 3-юю колонку 2 последних карточки)

```
<section class="we-produce section">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="we-produce__title section__title">[[*products_title]]</h2>

        <div class="we-produce__content">
            <div class="we-produce__cards">
                <div class="we-produce__col">
                    [[getImageList?
                        &tvname=`products_cards`
                        &tpl=`products_cardTpl`
                        &limit=`2`
                    ]]  
                </div>
                            
                <div class="we-produce__col">
                    [[getImageList?
                        &tvname=`products_cards`
                        &tpl=`products_cardTpl`
                        &limit=`1`
                    ]]  
                </div>

                <div class="we-produce__col">
                    [[getImageList?
                        &tvname=`products_cards`
                        &tpl=`products_cardTpl`
                        &limit=`2`
                    ]]      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

products_cardTpl:

```
<div class="we-produce__card">
    <img src="[[+image]]" alt="[[+title]]" class="we-produce-card__img">
    
    <div class="we-produce-card__info">
        <h3 class="we-produce-card__title">[[+title]]</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще в MIGX есть плейсхолдер `idx` (а еще `_first` и `_last`), можно в чанке анализировать его значение и выводить сообразно.

```
[[+idx:eq=`1`:then=`....`]]
[[+idx:eq=`2`:then=`....`]]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А как быть с 3 колонками, 3 tpl только одним не обойтись?

Comment: вы все условия можете в один единственный чанк прописать.. правда, это немного громоздко, но все же.